# Using Ripley's K Function in ArcGIS for coral density along a transect?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-statistics, autocorrelation

I have some data from transects taken in a mangrove system. I want to analyze the spatial distribution /some sort of spatial statistics of how clumped/dispersed corals are along this linear transect. We have GPS coordinates for each coral, as well as the measured distances between each coral. 
Does anyone have knowledge of how to conduct a spatial analysis of points along one line, using possibly Ripley's K or another function?